# Jmeter switch off the SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, jmeter, certificate

How to disable SSL certificate validation in Apache Jmeter 3.2
analogous to the switch in the postman "SSL-certificate verification on / off"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter does not validate certificate by default.
If you’re facing issues with ssl , it’s another cause.

As per your comment root cause was a missing header.
After adding those headers it worked:

> Accept-Enconding=application/json
>
> Content-Type=application / json

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is as follows: The data such as URL, port, protocol and the request itself is the same. In the Jmeter as well as in the Postman. If you do not turn off the SSL certificates in Postman the request will not work. Maybe you have an idea what the tools are different. With regard to the mentioned error.

Comment: Can you show the error you get ? jmeter.log + all tabs in View Results Tree. Thank you

Comment: The solution to the problem was the implementation of a header manager.
Accept ---------------------- application / json
Content-Type ------------- application / json
Thank you for your help.

Best regards
Jayo