# Disable JMeter SSL certificate parsing & validation

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to query an HTTPS REST API on a server that has a self-signed certificate.

I set up a HTTP Request and pointed it at my API. But when I run it, I get an error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to parse server certificates
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
```

How do I disable the SSL certificate parsing and validation?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339172/ignore-turn-off-verification-of-the-certificate-in-jmeter-java) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710697/jmeter-switch-off-the-ssl-certificate?rq=1) both say that JMeter doesn't validate SSL certificates. If that were true, then the fact that apparently my server's X509 certificate is invalid wouldn't be a problem. Those questions are very old, so possibly it is no longer the case that it doesn't validate by default any longer

I tried adding this property to my jmeter.properties file but it made no difference: `server.rmi.ssl.disable=true`. This was suggested in one of the above similar questions, (though I'm not sure why disabling SSL in RMI would have anything to do with HTTP.)

**How do I get JMeter to ignore the invalid self-signed certificate entirely for my https API request?**

Latest JMeter (5.4.1) and Java 8u311.

Comment: I found a solution for the problem. 
1. Create a batch file - setenv.bat with the following content:
set JVM_ARGS=-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true
2. Save it to the bin folder of the JMeter.
3. Run.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3280#section-4.1.2.4):

> The issuer field identifies the entity who has signed and issued the
> certificate.  The issuer field **MUST** contain a non-empty distinguished
> name (DN)

and [in RFC terms](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-1) **MUST** is really `MUST`

> MUST   This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the
> definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.

Actual JMeter documentation [states](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl):

> The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc. This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

So I would recommend reaching out to developers or system administrators and ask them to fix the certificate

If for some reason it's not possible you can try using HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS in your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

[image]

If your application doesn't expose HTTP endpoint the only thing you could do is to patch your Java runtime and [recompile](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/build/doc/building.html) it.

Comment: If your answer was true, then the Postman should also have had the similar behavior. There is a simple checkbox in Postman "SSL Certificate Verification". Once you turn it off, it will not perform any certificate verification and will work even with the self-signed certificates. This is not the case with the JMeter.

Answer (score -2):

Try disable antivirus.. sometimes it´s the solution.

Comment: What does antivirus have to do with handling invalid SSL certificates?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).